# Status of the $n$ conjecture and, as secondary question or reference request, what about a transfer method for this conjecture $n>3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, abc-conjecture

The [*n* conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_conjecture) is a generalization of the abc conjecture. What is the current status of the $n$ conjecture?  See also [1]

> **Question 1.** Can you tell us what about the current status of the $n$ conjecture, we consider $n>3$, of the $n$ conjecture?

One method of creating abc triples, that is triples which are close to being tight with respect to the abc inequality is the transfer method.

> **Question 2.** Is there a version of the transfer method for the $n$ conjecture?  (See Section 2.4 of [Martin and Miao - $abc$ triples](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2974).)

### References:

[1] Jerzy Browkin and Juliusz Brzeziński, [*Some remarks on the abc-conjecture*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153551), Math. Comp. **62** (206), (1994), pp. 931–939. ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1218341))

[2] Greg Martin and Winnie Miao, [*abc triples*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.facm/1481943880), Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. Vol. **55**, N. 2 (2016), pp. 145-176. ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3584566))

Comment: About the **Question 2**: A) I've known the transfer method from section *2.4. Transfer method* of the corresponding preprint on arXiv with identificator **1409.2974** (I believe thus that this is the corresponding preprint to [2]). B) Also, I don't know if does make sense  a LLL method for the $n$ conjecture, or if it is in the literature of the $n$ conjecture in some way.

Comment: Many thanks for your edit and help @JoshuaZ